# How to build OpenCV for Android using Clang and the latest NDK r15b

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, clang, android

How can I build OpenCV for Android using Clang and the latest NDK r15b?
On the latest NDK r15b *toolchains* folder does not contain special subfolders with Clang except *llvm* and *android.toolchain.cmake* script ignores *llvm* subfolder. So I can't figure out how to make things work?

Comment: Were you able to build OpenCV for Android using Clang?

Answer (score 1):

You can compile it like this:

```
cd $OPENCV_SRC_DIR
mkdir build
export ANDROID_NDK=$YOUR_NDK_PATH
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$YOUR_NDK_PATH/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake  ..
make -j7
make install
cd install
```

NOTE:

Tested with the last ndk16 version + opencv-2.4.11.

(Clang is the default compiler in the new ndk's)